# Unable to Record Video in Jenkins using ffmpeg in Windows System

Tags: jenkins, video, ffmpeg, protractor

I am using ffmpeg to capture video while running protractor scripts. Below ffmpeg code is working fine, when I directly run in windows from command line and able to create the video.

**`C:\Jenkins\workspace\test\node_modules\ffmpeg-binaries\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -s 1024x768 -i desktop -g 1000 -q:v 18 C:\Jenkins\workspace\test\AutomationVideo\Automation-11-7-2018-17.6.23.mpg`**

But when I run the same code through **jenkins(installed in windows system)**, showing below error and video is not getting recorded. Please help me in resolving the issue.

error is :[gdigrab @ 000002395689b400] **Capturing whole desktop as 1024x768x32 at (0,0)**

error is :[gdigrab @ 000002395689b400] **Failed to capture image (error 5)**
[gdigrab @ 000002395689b400] **Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: bmp, none, 754987 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options**

Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 754987 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, none, 754987 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc

Output #0, mpeg, to 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\test\AutomationVideo\Automation-11-7-2018-17.6.23.mpg':

Output file #0 does not contain any stream

============================================================

FFMPEG Binary Version used :4.0.0

Windows OS : Windows 10

Jenkins Version : 2.138.2